# Is John Durham handling all referrals from the IG investigation?

Tags: united-states, politics, criminology, donald-trump

Jerry Dunleavy said [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiE7qqS-vjkAhVqm-AKHd4AASkQzPwBCAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.washingtonexaminer.com%2Fnews%2Fu-s-attorney-john-durham-looking-into-ukrainian-involvement-in-2016-election&psig=AOvVaw2WmhWW-TuW7QgigihNTqwQ&ust=1569946914316442) on Wednesday in the Washington Examiner:

> Durham’s investigation is separate from the one that was just finished by DOJ Inspector General Michael Horowitz. The DOJ watchdog investigated allegations of abuses of the Foreign Intelligence Surveillance Act by the DOJ and FBI, and Horowitz has spoken with Durham, **who is handling any criminal referrals from Horowitz’s investigation.**

I’m interested in the part in bold.  To give context, Michael Horowitz, Inspector General for the Department of Justice, has just concluded an investigation into allegations of FISA abuse in the FBI’s Trump-Russia investigation.  And John Durham, US Attorney for the District of Connecticut, was tasked by Attorney General Bill Barr to look into the origins of the FBI’s Trump-Russia investigation.

My question is, is Dunleavy right that Durham is handling all criminal referrals arising from Horowitz’s investigation?

Comment: Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, he is.** [Here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/william-barr-interview-full-transcript-cbs-this-morning-jan-crawford-exclusive-2019-05-31/#) is what Attorney General Bill Barr said in an interview with CBS News on May 31:

> Right, so Huber had originally been asked to take a look at the FISA applications and the electronic surveillance but then he stood back and put that on hold while the Office of Inspector General was conducting its review, which would've been normal for the department. And he was essentially on standby in case Mr. Horowitz referred a matter to him to be handled criminally. So he has not been active on this front in recent months and so **Durham is taking over that role**.